# saving stream in .json file

Tags: json, stream

In the sample HupApp, I 'm modifying data and trying to save it in a .json file using following code:

The "jsonSerializer.WriteObject(stream, GroupsSource);" causes a problem that i cant fix.

what is wrong?

PS: I'm a newbie.

```
    public static async Task Save()
    {
        const string fileName = "PersonalSampleData.json";

        var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<SampleDataGroup>));

        using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
        {
            try
            {
                jsonSerializer.WriteObject(stream, Groups);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var err = e;
            }
        }

        try
        {
            using (var streams = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(fileName))
            {
                _groups = (ObservableCollection<SampleDataGroup>)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(streams);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var err = e;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You're saving "Groups" class not an object. You should put there an object and I suppose it's called "_groups" in your case.

Comment: Thx for replay. I is the same result.                                                            private static ObservableCollection<SampleDataGroup> _groups = new ObservableCollection<SampleDataGroup>();
        public static ObservableCollection<SampleDataGroup> Groups
        {
            get { return _groups; }
        }